# C++ memory management: creating a new array from vectors in a function

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, dynamic-arrays

Suppose I have a non-allocated array of floats say

```
float *a;
```

And then I use a function g where I expect to do the deallocation of the array of a outside the scope of the function (so I am calling g(&a)).

```
void g(float** f)
{
  std::vector<float> *v = new std::vector<float>(10);
  *f = &v[0]
}
```

Will this be a problem? I do feel that the allocation for v takes more space than that of a simple array of floats. So if I do delete *f outside the scope of this function, there might still be something left in the memory from the vector v. If so, how can one do this safely? The important thing (in my real function) is that I really need to use a vector inside g and that I really need to allocate *f inside g such that *f has the contents of v and does not disappear outside the scope of g.

Comment: This is super weird C++ code.  Raw double pointers, and dynamically-allocated vectors, are not idiomatic.

Comment: But yes, this will cause a problem.  Calling `delete` on `*f` will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, there is a vector member (`.data()`) rather than your `&v[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can envisage what this...

```
std::vector<float> *v = new std::vector<float>(10);
```

...does something like this:

```
1) At memory address &v std::vector<float>* v
                      |
                      v
2) At memory address v  std::vector<float>
                      |
                      v
3) At memory address v.data() aka &v[0]  floats[capacity]
```

**Of these three memory locations:**

1) goes is on the stack and goes out of scope when `g()` exits

2) sits there until `delete v` is done, which would never happen in your proposed code

3) may have been allocated by the vector, but the vector's also free to have allocated memory then started putting the float data at some offset into it, so any deallocation attempt using the address of data could result in deletion using an address that wasn't returned by `new` - that's undefined behaviour.  This is more likely than it sounds, as some memory allocated by `new[]` has to be used to store the number of elements so that `delete[]` can loop the right number of times calling their destructors - that might be before or after the data.  Of course, implementations may also put other things into the dynamically allocated memory: for example, values related to detecting accidental memory access immediately before or after the valid indices.

I wouldn't recommend it, but acknowledge that you could probably look at your `vector` implementation and work out to delete 3), but it would be non-portable and could break with optimisation levels and other compiler options.

You've no chance of deleting 2) with the code you propose - that might be acceptable leakage depending on your application.

**Overall, my advice from best to worst:**

1) I know you said you can't but I have to say it: rewrite the code to use/pass `std::vector<float>` by reference or value if at all possible, completely avoiding any explicit `new` and `delete`

2) copy the data from the `vector` to a plain float array if that's not way too slow for your needs

3) you say you need a `std::vector` inside `g()`, perhaps you could explore whether instantiation with an alternative allocator could give you well defined behaviour in terms of "unlinking" the allocated memory or (worse as it implies breaking dynamic resizing for `push_back` etc) specifying to the vector a `new[]`-ed buffer to use (but not `delete[]` on destruction)... I haven't looked into allocators enough to know how feasible this is.

4) you might be able to write a vector-like class with the behaviours you need, preferably a minimal interface just supporting what's absolutely necessary, but if you need extensive vector behaviour it may be best to bite the bullet and copy/modify a Standard `vector` implementation

Comment: I think your answer and the detail in which you explained it is great. The reason why I can't is because I need to pass things as a C-dll export function with the internal code being a C++ one which in itself uses a vector. Copying isnt at all slow. If it were, then I'd make my own pimpl in the export and try to work on pointers of them allowing me to use vectors. But since copying isnt slow I would rather stick to that.

Comment: I forgot to add that the export wants the required output be an array and I am internally using a C++ library that wants a vector. So.. I guess (2) :) .

Comment: 2 sounds ideal then... would be rare that it's problematically slow, especially as that implies the processing in `g()` being pretty trivial compared to the allocation and copying times.

Comment: just for the sake of curiousity though. Will a shared pointer on the vector solve this as well?

Comment: Unfortunately no - the C code won't know how to call the shared pointer's destructor, or indeed invoke its dereferencing functions etc..  If you really, really wanted to hack things around, you could intercept realloc/free calls and watch for the deallocation on .data(), then actually call the vector's destructor properly.  There's code around illustrating how to do it - I posted some myself in an old answer, think it was for documenting TCP API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be a problem: if you allocate a `std::vector<float>` with `new` you need to `delete` a `std::vector<float>` and there is no way to obtain the container from the address of an element. If I really had to allocate an array of something I'd probably do it like so

```
template <typename Range>
std::unique_ptr<typename Range::value_type[]> copy(Range const& r) {
    using value_type = typename Range::value_type;
    std::unique_ptr<value_type[]> rc(new value_type[r.size()]);
    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), rc.get());
    return rc;
}
```

Before doing something like that I would try hard to redesign what is being done, though.

Comment: so would the best way be to just go through the entries in the vector and copy the stuff in the array?

Comment: @Jose: No. The best approach would be to redesign the code to not do anything of that sort! I updated the answer with my take of how to write the function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here.

```
void g(float** f);  // will allocate a new array of floats.

// usage:
float* foo;
g(&foo);  // now foo is allocated.

// reclaim the memory:
delete [] foo;   // is this right?
free foo;        // is this right?
```

Any time you have a function that returns dynamically allocated memory, you need to know how it was allocated (new, new[], malloc), so that you can release it properly (delete, delete[], free).  If you cross the streams, bad things happen.

Now, for you particular section of code:

```
void g(float** f)
{
  //  This allocates a new vector.  Key words:  'new' 'vector'
  std::vector<float> *v = new std::vector<float>(10);
  *f = &v[0];  // Now you're returning a pointer to the internals of this new vector.
  // but then the vector [v] is forgotten, so how can you ever clean it up properly?
}
```

The only correct way to clean up `v` is to call `delete v;`  (`delete` because it was allocated with `new`).  But, outside of this function, there's no knowledge of the vector (anyone using this is going to think it just `new[]ed` an array).  So this won't work.

You could instead just use a vector for real:

```
void g(vector<float>* f);
// Usage:
//   vector<float> foo;
//   g(&foo);
```

No dynamic allocation, no `new`, no raw pointers, much cleaner.